# Circular dependency in BGL

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I am using [the boost graph library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/graph/doc/) and I need a way to remember some specific vertices in a directed graph (think of them as, say, remember which is/are the root node(s)). I would prefer this to happen within the graph data structure and I am wondering if this is possible to do in a clean way. The way I am imagining it is to keep the vertices in [the graph_bundle](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html), but (as far as I am aware) it will require something like:

```
template <typename Graph>
struct GraphProp{
  typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor SpecialVertex;
}

typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS, VertexProp, EdgeProp, GraphProp<TheThingAroundMe> >Graph;
```

In other words I get into the problem than I need to define something that depends on itself. However I would like to avoid using a `void*` in the `GraphProp`. Has someone had a similar problem, any ideas of a good workaround?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4755876/2417774

Comment: @cv_and_he good find. I guess we could vote as dupe?

Comment: @cv_and_he this exactly answers my question. Many thanks for that! Apologies for the dupe, I tried to find an answer before asking the question, but I guess I did not pick my tags properly.